# Some program icons are gone, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Pretty self explanatory, I moved some programs from Program Files (x86) from disk C to disk D, because I needed space on my C disk.

However, now, some of the application shortcut logos on the desktop are gone. Anyone have a fix?

Comment: Are you talking about shortcuts on the desktop? If so, did you update them to point to the new location?

Comment: That is what i'm talking about, and no, i don't know how to do that. Can you explain to me how i update them?

Comment: I would recommend uninstalling the applications from the C: drive and then reinstalling them on the D: drive, rather than manually moving them, which is what you, apparently, has done. That way everything (including shortcuts) should be taken care of by the installer.

Comment: Allright, that appears to be the thing i have to do. Is there a way i make everything install as default on the D disc?

Comment: Yes, it requires [some modifications](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-do-you-change-the-default-installation/73450b25-d794-4f18-9add-75253b893343?auth=1) in the registry editor, but it should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your icons are gone because the shortcuts are now pointing to an empty location.

Instead of manually moving an application's installation from one drive to another, it is recommended uninstalling the program from the drive, and the reinstalling it on the other drive. That way you ensure that all shortcuts, paths, registry keys and so on are created/updated by the installer.

If you want to change the default installation path to the second drive, it can be done by modifying the registry:

> To change the registry, follow these steps:
>   1.    Start Registry Editor by entering “Regedit” in the search All programs.
>   2.    Locate the following: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
>   3.    Right click on the value named ProgramFilesDir & change the default value C:\Program Files to the path you want to install all
>   your programs in.
>   4.    Click OK and Exit.
>
> Windows, by default, will now install your programs in the new drive or path.

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-do-you-change-the-default-installation/73450b25-d794-4f18-9add-75253b893343?auth=1)